# Should I use DB::rollback()?

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose I have codes as below

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
    ...
    DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    return back()->with('err', translate('something_went_wrong', 'Something Went Wrong. Please contact customer support.'));
}
```

Do I still need to call `DB::rollback()`? I saw similar codes on stackoverflow but I am wondering the necessity of having `DB::rollback()` because the transaction is never committed if something went wrong in between.

Comment: Yes, you can. You are doing it right.

Comment: @gre_gor, thank you, it does answer it to a certain extend. If we begin a DB transaction within a request lifecycle. will it be closed automatically when the request lifecycle ends? (Without committing the transaction). Or will the it be committed together with next successful transaction in another request?